# Prolog: How do I count the number of passes and failures for a predicate?

Tags: prolog

I want to count the number of successes AND failures for a predicate that doesn't have any arguments. For simplicity, the predicate I want to test is test_arith/0. test_arith/0 has 3 tests for is/2 (again, for simplicity. I really want to test more complicated predicates that I'm writing, but those details would be a distraction for this question.) (P.S. I saw the other question about counting the number times a predicate is true. I want to count both the successes and the failures in a single pass. I don't want to have to run the real predicates more than once per test case because some of them take a long time to execute. aggregate/3 and aggregate_all seem to be single-minded as well, taking only the successes.)

```
test_arith(Passes, Failures) :-
    findall(P-F, (test_arith->(P=1,F=0);(P=0,F=1)), Scores),
    summarize_scores(Scores, 0, 0, Passes, Failures).

test_arith :- 5 is 3 +2.  % Test #1: Should pass
test_arith :- 5 is 2 +2.  % Test #2: Should fail
test_arith :- 4 is 2 +2.  % Test #3: Should pass

summarize_scores([], Passes, Failures, Passes, Failures).
summarize_scores([P-F|Scores], Passes_SF, Failures_SF, Passes, Failures) :-
    Next_Passes is P + Passes_SF,
    Next_Failures is F + Failures_SF,
    summarize_scores(Scores, Next_Passes, Next_Failures, Passes, Failures).
```

When I run

```
test_arith(P,F).
```

I get

```
P = 1,
F = 0.
```

because test_arith seems to be called only once.
I should get

```
P = 2,
F = 1.
```

Thanks for any help you can give.

I tried:

```
test_arith(Passes, Failures) :-
    bagof(P-F, A^(test_arith(A)->(P=1,F=0);(P=0,F=1)), Scores),
    summarize_scores(Scores, 0, 0, Passes, Failures).

test_arith(_) :- 5 is 3 +2.
test_arith(_) :- 5 is 2 +2.
test_arith(_) :- 4 is 2 +2.

test_arith2(Passes) :-
    aggregate(count, A^test_arith(A), Passes).
```

test_arith(P,F) yields:
    P = 1,
    F = 0.
test_arith2(P) yields "2". (Which is good that it works, but only 1/4 of what I'm looking for. I need a count of failures and for each predicate to be run only once per test run, 3 calls in this case.)

Then I tried adding a number for each test case:

```
test_arith(Passes, Failures) :-
    bagof(P-F, A^(test_arith(A)->(P=1,F=0);(P=0,F=1)), Scores),
    summarize_scores(Scores, 0, 0, Passes, Failures).

test_arith(1) :- 5 is 3 +2.
test_arith(2) :- 5 is 2 +2.
test_arith(3) :- 4 is 2 +2.
```

and got:

```
test_arith(P,F).
    P = 1,
    F = 0.
```

Comment: You need to parameterize test_arith/0. Otherwise it just succeeds twice.

Comment: You need a number for each test case! Then can you count them.

Comment: Tried it...see above.

Comment: Almost: Currently you get only the successes. And you can imagine that the other numbers fail. Otherwise could enumerate them explicitly: `between(1,3,A), ( test_arith(A) -> ....` (It is not a good idea to remove A...)

Comment: test_arith_4(Passes, Failures) :-
 bagof(P-F, (between(1,3,A),(test_arith(A)->(P=1,F=0);(P=0,F=1))), Scores),
 summarize_scores(Scores, 0, 0, Passes, Failures).
yields:
test_arith_4(P,F).
P = 1,
F = 0 ;
P = 0,
F = 1 ;
P = 1,
F = 0.  If I add the existential A^, then it works! At least this one is back-tracking. But one bad thing: it relies on pre-knowledge of all the test numbers and that they must be contiguous. (Unrealistic for development.)

Comment: For the backtracking of bagof: you can make `bagof(P-F-A, ` for that. If you want to find out which numbers are present, you could use `clause/2`. Unfortunately, this requires either a system that permits `clause` on static predicates (e.g. SWI), or you have to make the preprocessing manually.

Comment: For the general solution to this you might look into plunit (**not** PL/Unit)

Comment: Thanks!  Any idea why the original version isn't working? Is it a bug in SWI or should it not work in any prolog?

Comment: In the original version you wrote `test_arith :- ...` so there was no way at all to distinguish the different cases. (You could give the testcases internal names like file:linenr, but this requires complete preprocessing.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/26405/discussion-between-chelmite-and-false)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like there is a typo in your findall, where the "else" of your implication binds F to both 0 and 1, instead of P to 0 and F to 1.  Is that copied directly from your code?

If so, that could be an explanation for why the aggragate methods only accept the trues; the false cases would never pass.

**Edited to add:**

Although I think it's a great practice to take advantage of functions like findall, sometimes you can't beat a good fail-loop; memory usage is quite a bit lower, and I find the performance to be similar.  In Sicstus prolog, my approach would almost certainly be something along the lines of this:

```
## function is passed in.
## call(Foo) succeeds.
evaluate(Foo) :-
    call(Foo),
    incrementSuccess,
    !.
## call(Foo) fails.
evaluate(Foo) :-
    incrementFailure.

incrementSuccess :-
    success(N),
    N2 is N + 1,
    retract(success(N)),
    assert(success(N2)),
    !.
incrementSuccess :-
    assert success(1).

[very similar for incrementFailure].

## A fail loop that evaluates all possible bindings
tally(Foo, _Success, _Failure) :-
    evaluate(Foo),
    fail.
## The catch case that passes out the final tallies.
tally(_, Success, Failure) :-
    success(Success),
    failure(Failure).
```

Comment: Yeah, I spotted that too, fixed it, ran it again, and still got the same output: test_arith(P,F).
    P = 1,
    F = 0. instead of P=2, F=1.

Comment: Does it have something to do with having a conditional as the bagof goal?

Comment: I wonder whether it has something to do with the variable A.  I'm not familiar with the carat operand (don't think it's a part of sicstus prolog), but in my experience variables in findall functions have strange binding behaviors when they are not specified in the template.  Why not try: bagof(P-F, (test_arith(_)->(P=1,F=0);(P=0,F=1)), Scores)  -- Does that give you an error?

Comment: test_arith_2(Passes, Failures) :-
 bagof(P-F, (test_arith(_A)->(P=1,F=0);(P=0,F=1)), Scores),
 summarize_scores(Scores, 0, 0, Passes, Failures).
gives:
P = 1,
F = 0.

Comment: Existential operator is in O'Keefe's book, and http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=bagof/3

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is the 'implicit cut' in (->)/2. Try

```
test_arith(Passes, Failures) :-
    findall(P-F, (test_arith, P=1,F=0 ; P=0,F=1), Scores),
    summarize_scores(Scores, 0, 0, Passes, Failures).
```

and you'll get

```
?- test_arith(P,F).
P = 2,
F = 1.
```

*edit*

OT, but I like when I can make the logic more compact, of course with a little help from the library. Here an equivalent definition:

```
test_arith(Passes, Failures) :-
    findall(R, (test_arith, R=1-0 ; R=0-1), Scores),
    aggregate(r(sum(A),sum(B)), member(A-B, Scores), r(Passes, Failures)).
```

and then, why to build a list to be immediately scanned?

```
test_arith(Passes, Failures) :-
    aggregate(r(sum(A),sum(B)), (test_arith, A=1,B=0 ; A=0,B=1), r(Passes, Failures)).
```

*edit* the above code is incorrect, being unable to count failures. I was fooled by the fact that it seemed to work with the specific test case.

With the help of @false, here is reify_call/3, a building block that could solve OP' problem (tested in SWI-Prolog, where [clause](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=clause/2)/2 is arguably extended with respect to ISO compatibility, given @false comment to question):

```
test_arith(Passes, Failures) :-
    aggregate(r(sum(T),sum(F)), reify_call(test_arith, T, F), r(Passes, Failures)).

:- meta_predicate reify_call(0, -, -).

reify_call(Pred, True, False) :-
    clause(Pred, Cl), (call(Cl) -> True = 1, False = 0 ; True = 0, False = 1).
```

Comment: You are incorrectly determining the number of failures: You will have always exactly one failure...